# Make the subfloat subcaption label in bold

Tags: subfloats, bold, subcaption

I'm managing my figures using subfig package. How can I get the subcaption label in bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[Caption 1]{\fbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\hfill}}}
\subfloat[Caption 2]{\fbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\hfill}}}
\caption{Big Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I want **(a)** and **(b)** instead of (a) and (b)

Comment: Would you accept switching to a more flexible package (`subcaption`)?

Comment: @TeXnician I have tryed subcaption, however, I needed foy subfig especificly. But, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\subfloat[Caption 1]{\fbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\hfill}}}
\subfloat[Caption 2]{\fbox{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\hfill}}}
\caption{Big Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```